# Can Horn's algorithm be generalized for all logic expressions?

Tags: algorithms, logic, computer-science

The following is an algorithm to find truth assignments for [Horn Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause):

> Input: A Horn Formula
>
> Output: A satisfying assignment, if one exists
>
> - Set all variables to false
> - While there is an implication that is not satisfied: Set the right hand variable of the implication to true
> - If all pure negative clauses are satisfied: Return the assignment.
> - Else:  Return "Formula is not satisfiable"

The book *Algorithms* defines a *Horn Formula* as a formula that consists of implications (left hand side is an AND of any number of positive literals and whose right hand is a single positive literals) and *pure* negative clauses, consisting of an OR of any number of negative literals.

Will the above algorithm work to identify truth assignments for expressions that are *not* Horn Formulas? For example, if a logic expression consists of *combinations* of positive literals and negative literals (and therefore violates the Horn Formula requirement for all expressions to be either implications or *pure* negative clauses), would this algorithm still work?

E.g: $(v_1∧ \bar{v_2} ∧v_3 )⇒v_4 ∧ v_5 $

The above expression is clearly not a Horn Formula: would the algorithm still be valid with these kind of expressions? If the algorithm does work on *any* logical expression set, then what makes Horn Formulas special? (since the generalization of the above algorithm would mean a linear time solution for all truth assignments as opposed to a linear time solution for only Horn Formulas)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can generalise your algorithm for arbitrary clauses, since arbitrary satisfiability is NP-complete whereas your algorithm is linear.

To understand why the algorithm works for Horn clauses let us identify a variable assignment $M$ with the set of variables that are assigned the value $true$. Consider a set $A$ of Horn clauses and let $A = D \cup N$, where $D$ is the set of definite clauses (clauses with exactly one negative variable) and $N$ is the set of all negative clauses.

Now any set of definite clauses has a least variable assignment (in the set inclusion order) that satisfies it. In the first part of your algorithm you construct the least variable assignment $M$ for $D$.

If $M'$ is a variable assignment that satisfies $A$, then it satisfies $D$ and so $M \subseteq M'$. But since the clauses in $N$ are all negative $M$ also satisfies $N$. Thus if $A$ is satisfiable then it is satisfied by $M$. So in the second part of the algorithm you just check whether $M$ satisfies $N$.

Comment: I understand why the algorithm works for Horn Clauses. Could you explain why it *doesn't* work for arbitrary clauses? (e.g. Possibly provide an example for arbitrary clauses)

Comment: The clause $v_1 \lor v_2$ for example does not have a least model. If you transform it to the implication $\lnot v_1 \to v_2$, then your algorithm will assign the value $true$ to $v_2$. Thus according to the algorithm the set $\{\lnot v_1 \to v_2, \lnot v_2\}$ is not satisfiable. But that is not correct.